# KISS approach to business logic in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, poco

Let's say I have this POCO in an EF code first context.

```
class A {
    //public properties 
}

class AViewModel {
    public int AvgSomething {get;set;}
    public int CalculatedValue {get;set;}
    //and so on, around 10 unique calculated values, based on the POCOs values.
    //In the calculations, other POCOs are used
}
```

Now, I want to create the view model from the POCO, and I don't know where to put the code that performs the calculations. I am reluctant to put it as public methods in the POCO, because I believe POCOs should be kept simple. I don't want to put it in the view model because I have read that view models should not contain methods. I don't want to put it in the controller because it is a lot of code. I am thinking of creating a bunch of extension methods for my POCOs but that feels wrong and I don't know why. 
What I have is a simple asp.net mvc app with models, repos for the models, viewmodels, controllers, that's all. Is there a BL missing? Should I create a bunch of NOPOCOs (Not Only Plain Old CLR Objects) to go along with the POCOs? Now that would violate my KISS belief!

To sum up, having a typical by the book asp.net mvc app, where should BL code go, if not in POCOs, VMs or controllers?

Answer (score 1):

You could consider a helper class to "translate" POCO's into view-models, and even use extension methods. This will let you easily convert POCO's into their respective view-models, but still keep the logic and the data separated logically. It would go something like this:

```
public static class PocoExtentions
{
    public static AViewModel ToViewModel(this A poco)
    {
        // convert poco to view-model logic
    }

    // more extension methods for other types of poco's...
}
```

And the usage will be simple and quite awesome:

```
AViewModel avm = aPoco.ToViewModel();
```

Comment: interesting solution, I like it

Comment: Of course, you will be adding all the parameters to the method which are required for the logic. I don't do much MVC, but if I did - I'd go with that.

Comment: just realized your idea might not work well if a viewmodel needs to be composed of several pocos. static AViewModel ToViewModel(this A poco, B poco2, C poco3)

Comment: @Balanikas it's your question, is that a requirement?

Comment: Why should that be a problem? If the return type logically represents a composition of several pocos, name it properly and construct it from all needed pocos as parameters. If the pocos aren't known in advance and should be read in some fashion, that's part of the conversion logic. Please [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) an example where this wouldn't be applicable.

Comment: @YoryeNathan no it's not a problem, I just implemented an ext method returning a viewmodel composed of several pocos, no problem. I was just quick to comment. Whats the protocol here? should I remove or leave my initial comment?

Comment: Leave it, and live with it until the last of your days.